# how to pass an array of pointers to a procedure in assembly model large?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, stack, procedure

i have a C code that defines a function, the function is implemented in ASM in model large memory.
the procedure receives an array of pointers (matrix) two integers and 4 pointers. inside the function i call another procedure which receives two arrays, two pointers and one integer.
now as i understand, when the call is initiated the parameters are passed through the stack, and in model large when a pointer is passed, the offset and segment of that pointer gets passed.
my question is, how do i pass 2 arrays from the array of pointer (i.e two pointers) to the other procedure? i have no trouble passing the integer and two pointers to the other procedure (i push the offset and segment of the pointers and then push the value of the integer)

here's my ASM code:

```
public _find_closest_matrix_pair
_find_closest_matrix_pair proc far
push bp
mov bp,sp
push si
push di
push es

mov ax,[bp+10]
mov n,ax
mov ax,[bp+12]
mov m,ax

mov es,[bp+28]
mov bx,[bp+26]
push es
push bx
mov es,[bp+20]
mov bx,[bp+18]
push es
push bx

mov ax,m
push ax

mov si,[bp+6]
mov es,[bp+8]
mov di,si
add di,2

push es
push word ptr [di]
push es
push word ptr [si]

Call find_closest_pair

add sp,18
;get returned value:
mov min1,0
add word ptr min1,ax
adc word ptr min1+2,dx
;update indices:
mov es,[bp+20]
mov bx,[bp+18]
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov j_min1,ax
mov es,[bp+28]
mov bx,[bp+26]
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov j_min2,ax
mov cx,0
mov es,[bp+16]
mov bx,[bp+14]
mov es:[bx],cx
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov i_min1,ax
inc cx
mov es,[bp+24]
mov bx,[bp+22]
mov es:[bx],cx
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov i_min2,ax

mov si,[bp+6]

mov s,0
loop1:
mov di,si
add di,2

mov bx,s
inc bx
mov k,bx
loop2:

mov es,[bp+28]
mov bx,[bp+26]
push es
push bx
mov es,[bp+20]
mov bx,[bp+18]
push es
push bx

mov ax,m
push ax

mov es,[bp+8]

push es
push word ptr [di]
push es
push word ptr [si]

call find_closest_pair

add sp,18
;get returned value:
mov temp,0
add word ptr temp,ax
adc word ptr temp+2,dx

mov ecx,temp
cmp ecx,min1
jae continue1
mov min1,ecx

;update indices:
mov es,[bp+20]
mov bx,[bp+18]
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov j_min1,ax
mov es,[bp+28]
mov bx,[bp+26]
mov ax,es:[bx]
mov j_min2,ax
mov ax,s
mov es,[bp+16]
mov bx,[bp+14]
mov es:[bx],ax
mov i_min1,ax
mov ax,k
mov es,[bp+24]
mov bx,[bp+22]
mov es:[bx],ax
mov i_min2,ax

continue1:
add di,2
inc k
mov cx,n
cmp k,cx
jb loop2
add si,2
inc s
mov cx,n
cmp s,cx
jb loop1

mov ax,0
mov dx,0
add ax,word ptr min1
adc dx,word ptr min1+2

mov cx,i_min1
mov es,[bp+16]
mov bx,[bp+14]
mov es:[bx],cx

mov cx,j_min1
mov es,[bp+20]
mov bx,[bp+18]
mov es:[bx],cx

mov cx,i_min2
mov es,[bp+24]
mov bx,[bp+22]
mov es:[bx],cx

mov cx,j_min2
mov es,[bp+28]
mov bx,[bp+26]
mov es:[bx],cx

pop es
pop di
pop si
pop bp
ret 
_find_closest_matrix_pair endp
```

note: find_closest_pair is the other procedure mentioned above.
thanks in advance.

Comment: "i have a C code that defines a function, the function is implemented in ASM" - Either it is defined in C or in Assembly language. As it looks, Assembly, so how is the C language tag relevant?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. When dealing with an array, the usual method is to pass a pointer to the first element of the array, and either a count or a pointer to the last element of the array or a pointer to the end of the array (one element past the last element).

Comment: @rcgldr i know how to pass an array in general but my question is how do i pass it in model large. Does each element have an offset and segment of its' own or do all elements have the same segment as the first element. I wrote the code in model small and everything works. but it's not working out in model large.

Comment: @iOSMaster - large model limits the size of each array to 64KB, so all elements of an array would have the same segment address. Huge model or at least a huge (__huge) pointer is needed if an array size is >64KB.

Comment: @iOSMaster -  For arrays larger than 64KB, huge model or at least a huge pointer is needed. For real mode, use halloc(). The C convention is for the base segment to be offset by a multiple of 0x1000, breaking up an huge array into 64KB chunks. Windows 3.1 has a protected mode alternative, using GlobalAlloc() and GlobalLock(), again using 64KB chunks, but the segment (selector since it's protected mode) is offset by a multiple of 8 for each 64KB chunk (this is setup by GlobalLock()).

Comment: So i should increase the offset by 4 every time i want to push a different array? The segment is constant?